Text in item doesn't align properly after math mode in enumitem
while making a numbered list (I'm using the enumitem package), I noticed how my code doesn't let text be properly indented after returning from math mode. Normally, text would be properly aligned in such case, like so:

(blue line manually added after compiling)
However, when I run my code instead:
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
{
\itshape
\begin{enumerate}[label={SV \arabic*.},wide=\parindent,font=\upshape]
    \item This item is fine.
    \[
        (u + v) + w = u + (v + w) \text{.}
    \]

    \item This item...
    \[
        O + u = u + O = u
    \] ...IS NOT.

    \item This item is fine.
    \[
        u + (-1)u = O \text{.}
    \]
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{document}


the text behaves as if it was a paragraph after leaving math mode

I'm pretty sure the culprit here is the wide=\parindent option in the code I'm using, but I need it.
Is there a way to align the "...IS NOT FINE" text in relation to where the item actually starts?
Thank you

Don't use wide. Math mode is completely irrelevant.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{showframe} % shows the text block

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={SV \arabic*.},wide=\parindent]

\item This item is fine.

\item This item has a long description that is so long that \TeX{}
      has to break it across lines. So you see what happens.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


You possibly want leftmargin=*,labelindent=\parindent.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{showframe} % shows the text block

\begin{document}

This text has a long description that is so long that \TeX{}
has to break it across lines. So you see what happens.

\begin{enumerate}[label={SV \arabic*.},leftmargin=*,labelindent=\parindent]

\item This item is fine.

\item This item has a long description that is so long that \TeX{}
      has to break it across lines. So you see what happens.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


